# Why does my count function stop counting the cells once I cross work order 9999?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the count formula on google sheets to calculate total work orders submitted and counting by the work order number. Well when my work order number crossed 9999, it stopped counting them in my formula. For example:

```
10098-1
9622-2
9545-1
9405-1
9895-2
8868-1
10000-2
10000-3
```

This would only count 5 total work orders when there is actually 8. Also, the work orders over 9999 are now formatted on the left side of the cell as opposed to the right. Any idea why?

Comment: cells formatted as text

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please add enough details so others can reproduce the problem without having to guess your context/setup.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your formula.  Try [COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991?hl=en) instead. It will count the number of values regardless if they are text or numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using `count()` to count numbers.

A value like `9622-2` will be interpreted by Google Sheets as the date 1 February 9622. Dates are numbers and will be included in `count()` results.

A value like `10098-1` will be interpreted as a text string that will not be included in `count()` results.

To count any type of values, including zero-length text strings `""`, use `counta()`, like this:

```
=counta(A2:A)
```

See [counta()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093991).